# Why isn't my end= variable ever being set to 1?

Tags: sas, datastep

The docs say that when an `end=` option on the end of a `set` statement will not work if you're using `point` or `by`, but the below code does neither and yet my final do block never runs.  Is there a way to get that to run?

```
data my_peeps ;
  input
    @1    mrn         $char10.
  ;
datalines ;
roy
mary
gene
bobby
joey
dee-dee
sting
evelyn
yo-mama
dude
dude2
bam-bam
;
run ;

data mrn_remaps ;
  input
    @1    mrn         $char10.
    @13   should_be   $char10.
  ;
datalines ;
roy         teddy
bobby       robert
yo-mama     mrs_p
dude        phil
dude2       phil
bam-bam     james
;
run ;

data corrected_peeps ;
  length should_be $ 10 ; * <-- needed for hash ;
  retain __num_corrections 0 ;
  set my_peeps end = last_record ;
  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    declare hash corrections(dataset: 'mrn_remaps') ;
    corrections.definekey('mrn') ;
    corrections.definedata('mrn', 'should_be') ;
    corrections.definedone() ;
    call missing (should_be) ;
  end ;

  * This while loop seems to be whats killing the end= block. ;
  do while(corrections.find() = 0) ;
    put "INFO: found a merged MRN. BEWARE OF DUPLICATES IN OUTPUT DATASET!" ;
    mrn = should_be ;
    __num_corrections = __num_corrections + 1 ;
  end ;

  if last_record then do ;
    put 'INFO: Corrected ' __num_corrections 'MRNs.' ;
  end ;
  drop should_be __num_corrections ;
run ;

proc print ;
run ;
```

Comment: Describe what's not working.  The posted code corrects 6 names originating my_peeps,  logs the correction count and prints out all 12 rows of corrected_peeps.

Comment: I ran your code and it executed the last block correctly. `INFO: Corrected 6 MRNs.`

Comment: Ack--you're both right. I'm sorry. I've adapted this from a real program where that's not working and somehow thought this was similarly not working.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: I have now fully elaborated this code to the point where it matches my real program as exactly as I can, and the problem I'm having persists in not reproducing.

I repent the question--sorry for any wasted brain cycles.  What's the remedy here--can I delete the whole Q?

Answer (score 0):

Codewise, you can let `.find()` perform the correction replacement, and `.check` if you find it necessary to log information.  These changes compact the code a little. It does require changing the remap table to have columns `old_mrn`(key) and `mrn`, instead of `mrn`(key) and `new_mrn`.

Example:

```
data my_peeps ;
  input
    @1    mrn         $char10.
  ;
datalines ;
roy
mary
gene
bobby
joey
dee-dee
sting
evelyn
yo-mama
dude
dude2
bam-bam
;

data mrn_remaps ;
  input
    @1    old_mrn $char10.
    @13   mrn     $char10.
  ;
datalines ;
roy         teddy
bobby       robert
yo-mama     mrs_p
dude        phil
dude2       phil
bam-bam     james
;

data corrected_peeps ;
  retain _count;
  set my_peeps end = last_record ;

  length old_mrn $ 10 ; * <-- needed for hash ;

  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    declare hash corrections(dataset: 'mrn_remaps') ;
    corrections.definekey('old_mrn') ;
    corrections.definedata('mrn') ;
    corrections.definedone();
    call missing(old_mrn); * <-- prevent uninitialized NOTE;
  end ;

  * if corrections.check(key:mrn) then 
      put 'INFO:' mrn= 'will be corrected';

  * increment counter and perform replacement of value in host variable if find succeeds;
  _count + (corrections.find(key:mrn) = 0);

  if last_record then do ;
    put 'INFO: Corrected ' _count 'MRNs.' ;
  end ;

  drop _:;
run ;
```